# Make Android device constantly be visible on network?

Tags: android, networking, ping

I want to make sure an Android (6.0.1) device is constantly visible on the internet it is connected to whilst the user can still use other apps.

Possibly ping to google.com all the time with some delay. I have made a Python 3 script that does exactly that, but the problem is that my phone (Samsung Galaxy s5) turns off automatically and that pauses the program.

Answer (score 0):

Android has two useful component for this:

1.[Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
2.[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Both components are useful for long-running task.

When your application goes to background none of task will execute until unless you use one of above-mentioned components.

Comment: I don't know Java very well, neither do I know how to create Android apps in it :/